# How to make a component show/hide on scroll in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a footer banner show only when user scrolls down past the header, and hide it when user scrolls up to top. My idea of how to implement this is to add an event listener for scroll event in the top component of the page. Here's my current code. But it doesn't work:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.nv.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll(e) {
  if(window.pageYOffset > 50 && window.pageYOffset < 900) {
    console.log('scrolled');
    this.setState({
      showBanner: true,
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      showBanner: false,
    });
  }
}
```

The render method of the top component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div ref={elem => this.nv = elem}>
      <Header/>
      <Body
        userInfo={this.props.userInfo}
        history={this.props.history}
      />
      {
        this.state.showBanner && <Banner/>
        || null
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't see any logs and the `setState` is apparently not called when scrolling.

Any suggestion on how I can accomplish the intended goal?

*** UPDATE ***
Changed `componentDidMount` to add event listener on window, now it's working.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is because you are trying to add an event listener to a ref that doesn't exist yet. `componentDidMount` happens BEFORE the initial render. That means that the ref you assign in render hasn't been set yet.

You can use a ref callback and attach the event listener there:

```
applyRef = ref => {
  this.vn = ref;
  this.vn.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
render() {
  return (
    <div ref={this.applyRef}>
      <Header/>
      <Body
        userInfo={this.props.userInfo}
        history={this.props.history}
      />
      {
        this.state.showBanner && <Banner/>
        || null
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Tried this. Still doesn't work. The `handleScroll` method is not called for some reason.

Comment: @NatashaC Seems like the `onScroll` event doesn't exist. Updated answer to show how to do this using a ref.

Comment: One caveat with this is that I think `applyRef` will be called on each render. So you should add some sort of check to make sure you are only attaching the event once.

Comment: For my purpose attaching the event on `window` in componentDidMount is good enough. I've updated the post.