# Scroll detection in react js using functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react js and wanted to show and hide a component on scroll down and scroll up in the function based component. thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a component show/hide on scroll in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347872/how-to-make-a-component-show-hide-on-scroll-in-react-js)

Comment: No Actually i specifically need this for functional component

Comment: Could you provide some example code or what you have done so far?